# JSON adding backslash automatically

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to convert a java object to json using Gson. But when i tried printing it out.I got this JSON

> {"user":"{\"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"lastName\":\"Las\",\"name\":\"amy\",\"password\":\"qwe123\",\"phone\":\"8901245244\"}"}

I tried

> s.replace("\\"", "\"") 
>   but neither it helps nor its a good approach.

Further I have gone through various links but answers are ambiguous.

This is my User class toString method

```
 public class User implements Serializable
{ ...
@Override
public String toString()
{   return "User{" +
            "first_name:" + name+
            ", last_name:" + lastName+
            ", mobile:" + phone+
            ", email:" + email+
            ", password:" + password+
            "}";
}
```

I guess its not even calling this toString method.

and here is how am I converting to JSON

```
        User u=new User(name,lastName,email,phone,password);
        Gson userGson=new GsonBuilder().create();
        String jo=userGson.toJson(u);

        JSONObject params=new JSONObject();
        params.put("user",jo);
        Log.e("in register",params.toString());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already converted it to a JSON string, then you stick that into a JSON object which automatically escapes the JSON string. Try something like this:

```
User u=new User(name,lastName,email,phone,password);
Gson userGson=new GsonBuilder().create();
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("user",user);
Log.e("in register", userGson.toJson(params));
```

Comment: If I simply output params its giving the same JSON as required and this userGson.toJson(params) is adding nameVAluPAirs like this : {"nameValuePairs":"user":"email":"ad@er.com","lastName":"Lad","name":"ad","password":"1234567890","phone":"1234567890"}}}

Answer (score 1):

`params.toString()` is a string representation of the JSON, not a User object.

> I tried  s.replace("\"", "\"")

You didn't need to do that... Java is showing the string with escape characters. If you see the escape characters, then you've converted an existing JSON string into another JSON object, and string-ed it again.

```
String jo=userGson.toJson(u);
```

Why are you not logging this instead?

> I guess its not even calling this toString method

Well, you never printed a User object