# JsonObject by default adding backslash to json string

Tags: java, json

I have list of items adding in to JsonArray and convert this JsonArray to string and adding this string JsonObject as a property. But While I am getting response is with back slashs.

```
jsonObject.addProperty("name",rsmd.getColumnLabel(1));
JsonArray itemJsonArray = new JsonArray();
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

while (resultSet.next()) {
   itemJsonArray.add(resultSet.getString(1));
}

jsonObject.addProperty("items",itemJsonArray.toString());         
jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "username",
    "items": [\"Mohan\",\"Mohan\",\"Mohan\"]             
}
```

Comment: Check out this question dude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161385/json-adding-backslash-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your problem is you are doing `itemJsonArray.toString()` and also you need to use `add()` instead of `addProperty()`, so:

Instead of

```
jsonObject.addProperty("items",itemJsonArray.toString());
```

Do this:

```
jsonObject.add("items",itemJsonArray);
```