# JSONObject.put(String) adds '\' for each '/'

Tags: java, android, json, string

I'm just recogniced that this code:

```
try {
        String jsonString =new JSONObject().put("test","Ha/llo").toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ouputs the following:

{"test":"Ha\ /llo"}

Does someone knows why it puts an \ for each / ? And how to get the real String?
My Strings i want to put are supposed to be big, so I dont want to search for \ to change it to ' '

Edit: .get decodes it again and removes the extra '\' in my case is was an server side problem.

Comment: Also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161385/json-adding-backslash-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is escaping the / character automatically. When a valid JSON client parses your string, it should unescape it, resulting in no issues and the original text.
See [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)